# Why won't this count variable increment?

Tags: c++, increment

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>
```

> This prints out "zero" for the count, even though I specifically increment count when I reach the desired character in the string.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userString = "I would like you to stop your chatting right now!";
    char userChar = 'o';

    int count = 0;

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++)
    {
        if (userString[i] == userChar)
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "There are a total of " << count << " " << userChar << "'s." << endl;

    int rnd; cin >> rnd;
    return 11;
}
```

Comment: Why is your `main` function returning 11?  Valid values are usually EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: Typo: remove the semi-colon at the end of the `for` line.

Comment: You would have noticed the typo if you had single stepped the program in a debugger.

Comment: The program works now, as everyone says I had a semicolon after my loop so it wasn't running the for loop code as expected!

Answer (score 4):

Remove the ; at the end of `for (i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++);`

You never loop over your code

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct code. You had added a semicolon at the end of for loop

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userString = "I would like you to stop your chatting right now!";
    char userChar = 'o';

    int count = 0;

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++)
    {
        cout <<userString.length();

        if (userString[i] == userChar)
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "There are a total of " << count << " " << userChar << "'s." << endl;

    int rnd; cin >> rnd;
    return 11;
}
```